# Inferred type is String but Nothing was expected

Tags: generics, kotlin

The code below fails to compile with the following error:

> ```
> Error:(28, 61) Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Nothing was expected
> ```

It's unclear to me why this is so. What I'm trying to achieve is for `filterMap` to take any kind of filter and apply it to incoming data. As you can see from the array used to test: `arrayListOf("Message1", 1, 'C')`. Is there anyway to achieve this? I can fix it by specifying `MutableMap<Filter<Any>, String>` and but then this mean my filters also have to be of type `(Any) -> Boolean`

```
class Filter<Q> (val predicate: (Q) -> Boolean, val isEnabled: Boolean) {

        constructor(predicate: (Q) -> Boolean) : this(predicate, false)

        override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
            if (other == null || other !is Filter<*>) {
                return false
            }
            return isEnabled == other.isEnabled && predicate == other.predicate
        }

        override fun hashCode(): Int {
            return 0x31 xor predicate.hashCode() xor isEnabled.hashCode()
        }
}

val filterMap: MutableMap<Filter<*>, String> = HashMap()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val messages = arrayListOf("Message1", 1, 'C')
    val isMessage1: (String) -> Boolean  = { it == "Message1" }
    val isMessage1Filter = Filter(isMessage1)


    filterMap.put(isMessage1Filter, "Matched Message1")

    messages.forEach { message ->
        filterMap.filterKeys { it.isEnabled || (it.predicate(message)) }
                .forEach {
                    it.value.forEach {
                        println(it)
                    }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter is defined with a star projection: `Filter<*>`, which results in a function `(Nothing) -> Boolean` when you take the functions from the map:

```
val pred = it.predicate //inferred type: (Nothing) -> Boolean
```

That's why the compiler does not accept `String` as an argument.

Also, your `messages` are of type `ArrayList<Any>`, you cannot just use them as `String`.

Kotlin is a statically typed language, it won't allow these unsafe attempts.

To fix this, you can change everything to `String` generics:

```
val filterMap: MutableMap<Filter<String>, String>> = mutableMapOf()
val messages = listOf("Message1")
```

I know, this won't be satisfying for you because you're looking for a generic solution. But then you would have to find a way to safely cast the entities you take from the unspecific collections.